# When running test project in Dot Net 4.6.1, SQLitePCLRaw throws TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, xunit, microsoft.data.sqlite

I have a test project targeting `net452`, `net461`, and `netcoreapp20`. Everything runs fine under `net452` and `netcoreapp20`, however, when I run `net461` I get a `System.TypeInitializationException`

here is the stack trace

```
Unhandled exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for "MyApp.SomeClass" threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Path is invalid.
   in System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   in System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)
   in SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.MakePossibilitiesFor(String basename, Assembly assy, Int32 flags, LibSuffix suffix)
   in SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.MyLoad(String basename, Assembly assy, Int32 flags, Action`1 log)
   in SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.Load(String libraryName, Assembly assy, Int32 flags)
   in SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.MakeDynamic(String name, Int32 flags)
   in SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.DoDynamic_cdecl(String name, Int32 flags)
   in SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()
```

I check the project output for my test project and all the DLL's are there as well as `SQLite.Interop.dll` in `./x86/` and `./x64/`

By the way my main project, I am using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and am targeting `net40`, `net461`, and `netstandard20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be with how xunit shadow copy feature and how SQLitePCLRaw dynamically loads the `SQLite.Interop.dll` 
When the test run xunit creates a shaddow copy of all the DLL's and places each of them in a separate randomly generated temporary folder i.e. `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\4c30a280-0900-4002-874b-a65591ef7c9e\4c30a280-0900-4002-874b-a65591ef7c9e\assembly\dl3\11289531\10e73523_73aed201\Some.dll`

When SqlitePCLRaw goes to find `SQLite.interop.dll` at runtime it looks inside the shadow copy folder instead of its original location.

The solution to this is to create a file `xunit.runner.json` in your test project and add it to your test project setting its build property to `Content` and setting CopyToOutputDirectory to `PreserveNewest`

Alternatively, if you are multi-targeting and only want to disable shadow copy for `net461` you can add the following to your test project file

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework) == 'net461'">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)xunit.runner.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```